# Installation of Skype 4.3. xx.yy. to Ubuntu 14.10. 64 bit

Tags: skype, synaptic

Thank you for many replies and great interest to this topic, but I would like to repeat my original question: Can I use without problems Synaptic for this installation.

**Reason:** I would like NOT to use terminal commands if possible with Skype installation.

**Background:** I have made last week installation with terminal commands by using the instructions / command shown above in answer ''Step 1, Step2, Step 3 ..'', but I made some mysterious misstake(s) and I greated somehow a ''SystemEror level problem'' (= in /etc/.. line 54 was lost for some reason ... -> SystemError warning)

**Result:** I did not find any way / method / command to sort it out, than to REINSTALL the whole Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Finish remix) once again -> then upgrade it to Ubuntu 14.10.. and, as you understand, it is not so nice excersice to repeat ....)

**Conclusion:** So, Synaptic may be a safe solution, if Skype 4.3. works OK in Ubuntu 14.10. with this skype 4.3.0.37-OubuntuO12.04.1 packet version. This packet version at present Synaptic offers me for installation.

Comment: Yes Synaptic is safe, Skype 4.3 is old, but still works fine, we all use that!
See answer below!!
Remember to allow skype to use camera and mike!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by opening the Software & Updates application, and tabbing to "Other Software".

Enable the "Canonical Partners" check boxes. Close the application. It will give you a message about packages being out of date. Select "Reload".

Open synaptic and search for skype after the reload is finished.

Mark for installation, and apply changes.

Comment: I am repeating this same question once more, beacuse Skype web pages indicate that their skype 4.3. packet version is for Ubuntu 12.04; and the same is indicated in Synaptic. So, does it work also in Ubuntu 14.10 ?Kauko Peltonen

Comment: I installed and tested in 14.04.2 and it worked fine. I imagine that it should work in 14.10

Comment: Brian hi, thank you for your info ! Please inform also did you install Skyto 4.3 to your 14.04.2 with Synaptic or did you use some other method (like terminal commands) ? Brgds, Kauko

Comment: Brian hi, sorry to disturb, but does your previous comment (16 h ago) already say / mean, that your used Synaptic to install skype4.3 packet to your 14.04.2 ? Brds, Kauko

Comment: Yes it does. I used synaptic to install to 14.04.2 just as described in my answer.